# Como comparar hash vindo por JSON no RAILS

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, hash

Pessoal criei um web service que hoje recebe um registro e uma senha, ele faz um select no banco e compara ver se o registro e senha são iguais, se sim ele mostra algumas opções.Porem nesse momento a senha está sendo enviada em texto puro, gostaria de implementar segurança nela, seja via hash ou de outra forma...

Eu gostaria que a aplicação  ao inves de enviar `registration":102030"` quero receber um `hash` e comparar ele com o hash do BD;

**Controler**

```
def index
  student = Student.new
  return_dados = student.sqlValidatedLogin(params[:registration].to_s,params[:password].to_s)
  render :json => return_dados
  end
```

**Model**

```
def sqlValidatedLogin(registration,password)
        query_student = "SELECT id, name, registration FROM students WHERE registration = "+
        registration+" AND password = "+password
        ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query_student)
end
```

Alguem tem alguma ideia de como eu posso não enviar a senha em texto puro do Mobile via JSON

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Sugiro que você dê uma olhada nesse [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/352-securing-an-api?view=asciicast) que fala exatamente sobre autenticação via token.

Answer (score 1):

JWT é o caminho.

De uma olhada neste post:

https://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-to-using-jwt-in-rails/